# How to make an onscreen counter that blocks the function till a counter is done

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my website I want to display an onscreen event once a button is clicked to record a wbcam (so that people know when the recording starts).

I want to use a jQuery/JavaScript method that once called, blocks the function that is running and displays "3, 2, 1" (counting down) in screen. After that I want the function to continue.

I found the JQuery AnimateCount function and a [jquery-count-to plugin](https://github.com/mhuggins/jquery-countTo) but I cannot get it to work.

Can someone help me out?

/edit non-working code:

I have a function that starts the recording of the webcam as follows:

```
function startRecording() {
    $("#recordStartButton").attr("disabled", true);
    $("#recordStopButton").attr("disabled", false);
    $("#recordPauseResumeButton").attr("disabled", false);
    $.scriptcam.startRecording();
}
```

I call this function once a user clicks "Start Recording" with a function that has a callback as follows:

```
<button id="recordStartButton" class="success" onclick="startRecordingWithCounter(startRecording)" disabled>Start Recording</button>&nbsp;
```

where startRecordingWithCounter(startRecording) looks like this:

```
function startRecordingWithCounter(callback) {
    $('#message').animateCount(1, 3);
    callback();
}
```

this only displays "3" in the message div and then just starts recording...

Comment: Can you post your non-working code?

Comment: You want to record streaming data from the webcam, but you are not able to countdown from 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
$('#message').animateCount(1, 3);
callback();
```

Tells the plugin to start a count animation.  But that call does not "block" until the animation is complete - it returns from the function immediately.  (This is important since Javascript is a single-threaded language.  Locking functions would cause ugly browser freezes.)

So the `animateCount` function returns immediately, and `callback` is called immediately!

However the library you are using does allow you to specify an `onComplete` function.  So you should do it that way:

```
$('.message').countTo({
    from: 1,
    to: 3,
    speed: 3000,
    refreshInterval: 50,
    formatter: function (value, options) {
        return value.toFixed(options.decimals);
    },
    onComplete: callback
});
```

The library should call your `callback` function when the animation has finished.

I don't know if you need to provide the `formatter` function or not.

---

An alternative would be to simply change your current code from:

```
callback();
```

to:

```
setTimeout(callback, 3000);
```